# googletrans problem, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, google-translation-api

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator

d = {"City_trad_chinese":["香港特别行政区",
                      "澳门特别行政区",
                      "北京市",
                      "上海市"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

translator = Translator()

df["City_English"] = df["City_trad_chinese"].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src="zh-TW", dest="en").text)
```

I've got this Code snippet from this [StackOverflow_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796361/python-pandas-create-a-new-column-with-values-in-english-by-converting-values-s):

I want to create this after code snippet:

```
print(df["City_English"])

0    Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
1        Macao Special Administrative Region
2                               Beijing City
3                              Shanghai City
```

---

But when I try it, I'll get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-d5e66e13e679>", line 1, in <module>
df["City_English"] = df["City_trad_chinese"].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src="zh-TW", dest="en").text)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2996, in map
arg, na_action=na_action)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1004, in _map_values
new_values = map_f(values, mapper)

  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "<ipython-input-30-d5e66e13e679>", line 1, in <lambda>
df["City_English"] = df["City_trad_chinese"].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src="zh-TW", dest="en").text)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 172, in translate
data = self._translate(text, dest, src)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 75, in _translate
token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 180, in do
self._update()

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 59, in _update
code = unicode(self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1)).replace('var ', '')
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

How can I resolve to the above error?

---

[**NOTE**]:

System information:

- Windows10
- Anaconda package
- Spyder IDE

Comment: The compiler already tells you where the error is: ``code = unicode(self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1)).replace('var ', '')`` - it is telling you that ``self.RE_TKK.search(r.text)`` returns ``None``.

Comment: This is probably not the cause of the error, but the Chinese in your post is actually Simplified, not Traditional.

Comment: But in [link](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are also Examples:

`from googletrans import Translator`
`translator = Translator()`
`translator.translate('안녕하세요.')`

I'll get also the same ErrorMessage

Other Languages I've tried also:

`translator.translate('veritas lux mea', src='la')` 
get's the same ErrorMessage also:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Comment: It looks like something has changed in `googletrans` since that answer was posted so I don't think the code is wrong but it's a bug in the latest release as I get the same error with googletrans 2.3.0 and running the example code on the website. https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/88 there is a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group/52487148#52487148 so I'd try editing gtoken.py with the answer in the link

Comment: I've found the Workaround also but it is also incompatible for me...
If I use it, I'll get:

`AttributeError: 'TokenAcquirer' object has no attribute 'RE_RAWTKK'`