# How to extract content in specific javascript tagsin python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the entire schedule and results of the Dota2 TI9 international from [this page](http://www.dota2.com/international/schedule/0/0/?l=english).
The information I seek is under a  tag and under 'schedule_data'.

So far this is what I have got

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://www.dota2.com/international/schedule/0/0/?l=english'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text,'html.parser')
all_javascript = soup.find_all(name='script',type='text/javascript')
all_javascript[:] = [x for x in all_javascript if(re.search("schedule_data",x.text))]  
data = all_javascript[0]
new_data = json.loads(data.text)
```

I find all the 'script' tags and then search for the 'schedule_data' pattern to identify the tag I need. However, now the last line fails with the error

```
new_data = json.loads(data.text)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-447d26a16d5b>", line 1, in <module>
    new_data = json.loads(data.text)

  File "C:\Users\templ\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\templ\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\templ\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

I looked at the solution here [json loads example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573197/python-error-load-json-code-of-google-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0), but  none of these resolve the issue. These examples seem to suggest that it is a url request failure or a translation error that leads to json loads failure, but I have neither of these.

```
print(type(data.text))
```

returns str for me which i understand to be the correct data type for json loads.

Please help

Comment: Can you please mention what output you need?

Comment: Why the `all_javascript[:] =` ? Please share the relevant HTML as well as the values in your program, see [mcve].

Comment: I need to extract match ID's, start time and end times and winner by game.I am trying right now to get match ID's, winners and losers from this source and use https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{match_id} to get the relevant match start and end times. I want to put this all into a nice excel that looks like this:[Match ID, StartTime(EDT), Date, Day, Match Length, Team A, Team B, Winner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this.

```
import requests, re, json
import ast

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://www.dota2.com/international/schedule/0/0/?l=english'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text,'html.parser')
all_javascript = soup.find_all(name='script',type='text/javascript')

for x in all_javascript:
    if re.search("schedule_data", x.text):
        data = str(x).split("$( '#ScheduleArea' ).tournamentSchedule(")[1].split(');')[0].strip().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '')
        data_dict = ast.literal_eval(data)
        print(data_dict['schedule_data'])
```

Comment: Thanks :) This worked. I started reading about Abstract  Syntax trees but I am not sure I understand completely what the code is doing. Is there an ELI source for this?

Comment: No problem , Once text is matched in **if re.search("schedule_data", x.text):**. I am trying to split code based on **$( '#ScheduleArea' ).tournamentSchedule(** this contains dict what you need so I am taking index 1's data and then again split until ***$( '#ScheduleArea' ).tournamentSchedule(** closing bracket so split is based on **);** then just replacing \n\t\r thats it.

Comment: @VaidyanathanViswanathanSauna If you find this answer acceptable, you should accept it, as the responder spent time and effort putting the answer together.